# Cannot change Views at Runtime in Dialogfragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to set the drawable of a `ImageView` and a `ProgressBar` in a DialogFragment at runtime. Therefore i want to set the drawable in the onViewCreated and set the ProgressBar visible when the Positive Button of the Dialog is clicked.

But for reasons i do not know absolutely nothing happens. i also tried to call invalidate on the view to actively trigger a redraw but also nothing happens.

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, container, false)
}

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val inflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater
    val layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null)
    val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title)
        .setMessage(R.string.dialog_text)
        .setView(layout)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.start, null)
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null)
        .create()

    return dialog
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    imageView.setImageDrawable(image) //image is a drawable
}


override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    val d = dialog as AlertDialog?
    d?.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)?.setOnClickListener {
        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Found out that if i directly call something on the layout i pass to the dialog it is possible to change visibility of views.

```
val layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null)
layout.findViewById ....
```

This works but i still wonder why i cannot simply call with kotlin synthetics on the view.

Answer (score 0):

The action that you want to be performed when the positive button is pressed should be added in the dialog build

```
.setPositiveButton(R.string.start){ _, _ ->
          progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
```